# How to remove my user account from application users on googe play console?

Tags: android, console, google-play

I was added as a user on the google play console for an app some time ago. Since then the admin developer has quit maintaining this account.
I want to remove myself from the users of that group in the google play console, but i can't find this function. any help ?

Comment: Are you an application admin?

Comment: I have admin rights but i am not the admin of that developer account

Comment: @OrenKochansky have you solved this? I have the same issue.